# JS script to populate text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an intake request form that I am working on and I am trying to populate a form input based on whether certain radio buttons are checked (populating email subject based on answers in form). I have the below code at the bottom of my `<body>` and have also tried it in the `<head>` with no success. Any thoughts on why this doesn't seem to be working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (form.id1.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line";
        }

        else if (form.id2.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line";
        }

        else if (form.id3.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line";
        }           

        else if (form.id4.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line";
        }   

        else if (form.id5.checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line";
        }

        else {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "unknown";
        }
</script>
```

Based on the answer from @mhatch I've updated my code to the following, but am still having issues. I'm probably missing something simple/basic at this point, but am stumped as to what

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleChange()
{
    var value = document.form.Request_Type.value;
        if (value == "Request_Access") {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line 1";
        }

        else if (value == "Request_Support") {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line 2";
        }

        else if (value == "Request_Reporting") {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line 3";
        }           

        else if (value == "Request_Retire") {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line 4";
        }   

        else if (value == "Request_Other") {
            document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line 5";
        }

        else {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line - Unknown";
        }
}       
</script>

<input type="radio" name="Request_Type" onchange="handleChange();" value="Request_Access" id="access">
<input type="radio" name="Request_Type" onchange="handleChange();" value="Request_Support" id="support">
<input type="radio" name="Request_Type" onchange="handleChange();" value="Request_Reporting" id="reporting">
<input type="radio" name="Request_Type" onchange="handleChange();" value="Request_Retire" id="retire">
<input type="radio" name="Request_Type" onchange="handleChange();" value="Request_Other" id="other">
```

Comment: You have double double-quotes on the left of EMAIL_TITLE.

Comment: Also this will run when the page loads, not as a result of selecting a radio option.  That may not be what you are expecting...

Comment: sorry, that's not in my actual code just a mistype from when I was taking out any sensitive info, I'll edit my post to correct.

Comment: Are you trying to set EMAIL_TITLE when the user clicks on the radio button or just check if it is checked?

Comment: You need to attach your logic to an event

Comment: This populates a form for a form handler, so I just need EMAIL_TITLE set before it sends to the form handler (sends after clicking a submit button).

Comment: Also, you should ensure the script executes after page load is complete... Wrap in `window.onload = function () { ..... }`

Comment: You will need to attach an event listener, which listens to click/change events on the radio button which will then trigger this logic. Otherwise as what @JayBuckman said, your logic will only run at runtime and only once.

Comment: @Dayan The function will not be called until a button is clicked, so attaching it to the `onload` event is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if they are radio buttons, they need to have the same `name` attribute. The code `form.id1.checked` suggests that each button has its own name value. This will cause all the buttons to be clickable at the same time. If this is what you want, you should use checkboxes.

Secondly, you need to attach your logic to an event.

I imagine you are looking for something like this:

```js
function handleChange(){
 var value = document.form.id.value;
 if (value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line1";
    }

    else if (value == "2") {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line2";
    }

    else if (value == "3") {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line3";
    }           

    else if (value == "4") {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line4";
    }   

    else if (value == "5") {
        document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "subject line5";
    }

    else {
    document.getElementById("EMAIL_TITLE").value = "unknown";
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="form">
 <input type="radio" name="id" onchange="handleChange();" value="1" />
 <input type="radio" name="id" onchange="handleChange();" value="2" />
 <input type="radio" name="id" onchange="handleChange();" value="3" />
 <input type="radio" name="id" onchange="handleChange();" value="4" />
 <input type="radio" name="id" onchange="handleChange();" value="5" />
 <input type="text" name="title" id="EMAIL_TITLE" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: This look like exactly what I need, thank you! Regarding the name attributes, I do have them all set to the same name just different values, I should have dictated that differently in my code to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ddrees If this solves your problem, please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm still having issues after updating my code with your suggestion. I updated my original post with how my code looks now after your recommendations.

Comment: Take a look at this line `var value = document.form.Request_Type.value;` Are your inputs in a form tag? Dot notation uses the name attribute, so `document.[form-name].Request_Type.value`

Comment: My inputs are in a table tag within a form tag.

Comment: And what is the form `name` attribute? The line you have assumes that you have `<form name="form">` If it is something else like `<form name="other">`, then you would change your var to `value = document.other.Request_Type.value;`